# cannot select the case when col to count

Tags: sql, hive

This is the SQL query I wrote:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS TOTLA_COUNT,  
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN ( market_val > 0 AND ABS( loan_amt / market_cal * 100 - ratio ) > 5 ) THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS FAIL_COUNT,  
    COUNT( FAIL_COUNT / TOTAL_COUNT * 100 ) AS FAIL_RATE  
FROM
    MY_TABLE
```

but I get an error

> Reason for Error is cannot resolve 'market_val' given input columns

May I know how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: Show us your `CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE` statement.

Comment: Also, `COUNT( FAIL_COUNT / TOTAL_COUNT * 100 ) AS FAIL_RATE` is not a meaningful calculation...

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. We can't help you if we don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other Way.

AsIs:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS TOTLA_COUNT,  
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN ( market_val > 0 AND ABS( loan_amt / market_cal * 100 - ratio ) > 5 ) THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS FAIL_COUNT,  
    COUNT( FAIL_COUNT / TOTAL_COUNT * 100 ) AS FAIL_RATE  
FROM
    MY_TABLE
```

ToBe:

```
SELECT a.TOTLA_COUNT, a.FAIL_COUNT
  , FAIL_COUNT / TOTAL_COUNT * 100 AS FAIL_RATE  
FROM (
  SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS TOTLA_COUNT,  
      COUNT(
          CASE
              WHEN ( market_val > 0 AND ABS( loan_amt / market_cal * 100 - ratio ) > 5 ) THEN 1
              ELSE NULL
          END
      ) AS FAIL_COUNT
  FROM
      MY_TABLE
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

FAIL_COUNT and TOTLA_COUNT are alias names you can't perform operations on it.

Comment: than may i know how can i use that col?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).